# Use sed to remove string, add whitespace and insert ""

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with the following entry:

```
export TF_VAR_environment_name=dev
export TF_VAR_project_name=hello-world
```

I would like to do 3 things with these enteries:

1. Remove the **export TF_VAR_** string
2. Add **whitespace** to both sides of **=**
3. Wrap the string right of **=** in **" "**

So my file would end up looking like:

```
environment_name = "dev"
project_name = "hello-world"
```

I'm able to remove the string with **s/"export TF_VAR_"//**, but haven't been able to wrap the = in whitespace, or wrap the final string in quotes. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Is this possible to do in sed?

Comment: Most probably yes, please post what have you tried so far? Where did it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input.txt is your textfile.
output.txt is the wanted result.

sed 's/export TF_VAR_// ; s/=\ (.*\ )$/ = "\1"/ ' < input.txt  >  output.txt

there is no blank between   \  and (
and no blank between   \   and )

Comment: Thank you for the response. This currently gives the following error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 39: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Anything in the syntax looking incorrect?

Comment: Add option `-E`.

Comment: I'm using macos (m1), and also testing in https://sed.js.org/ 
Both have the error I mentioned above

Comment: -E flag worked, thank you @Cyrus

Answer (score 0):

input.txt is your textfile. output.txt is the wanted result.

```
sed 's/export TF_VAR_// ; s/=\(.*\)$/ = "\1"/ ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

its the same as above.  i just tried to post it here in a correct way.

Comment: You can just edit your original answer. If you don't have 2 distinct answers, you should always try to edit the original answer when adding more information or editing formatting :)